# Integral boundary inconsistency

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm attempting to calculate the area under a simple curve with a boundary in x and a boundary in y namely, $\{x,-1,1\} \left\{y,0,e^x\right\}$

[image]

The bottom line is y = $\frac{1}{e}$ and the top line is y = ${e}$

Given the double integral of:

$$\int _{-1}^1\int _0^{e^x}ydydx$$

Solving via mathematica gives:

$$\frac{e^2}{4}-\frac{1}{4 e^2}$$

However, when solving by hand, seperating and changing the boundries a bit...

$$\int _0^{\frac{1}{e}}\int _{-1}^1ydxdy+\int _1^e\int _{\log (y)}^1ydxdy$$

I get the solution of:

$$\frac{1}{4} \left(e^2-3\right)+\frac{1}{e^2}$$

Which seems to be quite off to me...What am I missing when calculating by hand?

To add some extra content as to the frequently asked *why?*

I am trying to understand the reasoning behind this given example of a solution path, which seemed as others have pointed out...out of the way,

Mathematica appears comes to the same conclusion as the example...but I didn't following their method.

[image: thing]

Comment: Can't you just subtract the integral of the bottom part from the integral of $e^x$?

Answer (score 1):

The first integral should be$$\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{e^x}1\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=2\left(e-\frac1e\right).$$The second integral also doesn't give you the area of that region.

Comment: It should be as I gave it, I would expect.

Comment: And what makes you think that, in order to computa the area of a region $A\subset\mathbb R^2$, you need to compute the integral of $y$? Why not, say, $x$, instead of $y$? The area is $\int_A1\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$.

Comment: You arn’t including the entire area, see updated question.

Comment: Is the region the blue region from your second picture?

Comment: Ah yes it is. And to answer your prior question, I most certainly don't have an in depth knowledge of solving integrals over regions, if that wasn't clear enough as it is, I appreciate the help. But I'm looking for an explanation on the question ( I admit, my drawing clearly wasn't clear enough ) And not using other methods that are better or whatever.

Comment: It is not a matter of being better. The area of that region is $\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{e^x}1\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$, and not $\int_{-1}^1\int_0^{e^x}y\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx$

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to separate boundaries or anything? Proceeding directly gives $$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_0^{e^x}y\mathrm d y\mathrm d x=\frac12\int_{-1}^{1}e^{2x}\mathrm d x=\frac14\left(e^2-\frac{1}{e^2}\right).$$

Comment: Please see updated question as to why. Thanks however, your method is what I would have thought to do.

Comment: @morbo Well, I see. It seems they wanted to illustrate how to change the order of integration. In that case again, just integrate directly. For example, the second integral (since someone has solved the first below) will become $\int_1^e (1-\log y)y\mathrm d y.$ Expanding the integrand gives $y-y\log y.$ The first is easy. The second may be done partially to give $\log y\int y-\int \frac1y\cdot \frac{y^2}{2},$ and so on. Can you confirm that this was what you did, since you don't actually provide your work; otherwise it would have been easy to spot where the error might be hidden.

Comment: Thank you @Allawonder, that is what I would have expected to do aswell. It appears my partial integration is shoddy, I will have another attempt at it, and if I fail again, update the question with my work. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @morbo Glad to have been of help.